# QtCreator. Переход к телу функции. Подсветка переменных

Tags: qtcreator

- Как в QtCreator при включенном отображении проекта в виде списа классов при двойном клике на имени функции класса переходить не в заголовочный файл к объявлению функции, а в реализацию функции в файле *.cpp
- Как в при включенной теме Dark изменить цвет рамки, возникающей при выделении переменной в теле функции. Проблема в том, что светлой теме хорошо просматриваются все места использования переменной в функции, а в теме Dark видно только рамку, да и та сливается с темным фоном.

Comment: Вряд ли можно перейти сразу в реализацию, но, перейдя в заголовочный файл на строку с требуемой функцией, можно нажать F2. Тогда перейдёт в реализацию.

Comment: с точки зрения эргономики, светлый фон лучше для глаз, темный лучше с точки зрения производителй дешевых дисплеев (вредный синий и т.п.)

Answer (score 0):

Из заголовочного файла, помимо нажатия <kbd>F2</kbd>, можно перейти в реализацию через зажатый <kbd>ctrl</kbd>.

В Options -> Text Editor -> Font & Colors (Параметры -> Текстовый редактор -> Шрифт и цвета) можно сменить цветовую схему для текста (например, на другую тёмную, в которой другая рамка) или настроить её под себя путём копирования. За рамку переменных отвечает пункт Occurrences (Совпадения).

Comment: "За рамку переменных отвечает пункт Occurrences (Совпадения). " - Спасибо! Помогла подсказка.

Comment: Осталось выяснить есть ли возможность сразу в тело функции переходить. Минуя заголовочный файл.